# MySQL counting records from a group

Tags: mysql

When I execute the command below it tells me

> #1247 - Reference 'StockCount' not supported (reference to group function)

```
SELECT stockSymbol, count(*) as StockCount 
FROM US500 
group by stockSymbol 
AND StockCount > 100 
ORDER BY stockSymbol DESC
```

whats going on why is it not working.

Comment: Conditions on aggregates need to be done through `having` not in the `where` clause.

Comment: Replace `and` with `HAVING`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SELECT` and any `WHERE` clause is applied before any aggregate `GROUP BY` functions.

You'll get an error about unknown column `StockCount` in the `WHERE` clause if you try this:

```
SELECT stockSymbol, count(*) as StockCount 
FROM US500 
WHERE StockCount > 100 
GROUP BY stockSymbol 
ORDER BY stockSymbol DESC
```

Instead, use `HAVING` which occurs after `SELECT`, `WHERE`, and `GROUP BY` to apply conditions to aggregate results from `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT stockSymbol, count(*) as StockCount 
FROM US500
/* WHERE clause would go here */
GROUP BY stockSymbol
HAVING StockCount > 100 
ORDER BY stockSymbol DESC
```

`ORDER BY` occurs last, so you can also reference the aggregate column there if you wanted to:

```
SELECT stockSymbol, count(*) as StockCount 
FROM US500 
GROUP BY stockSymbol
HAVING StockCount > 100 
ORDER BY StockCount DESC
```

The order of the clauses in your query should give you some idea of the order in which they are processed. E.g. the `GROUP BY` clause must be after the `WHERE` clause and `HAVING` must be after `GROUP BY`.